# Adding an image to: month event title display; week/day information

Tags: fullcalendar

1. On the month view, is there a way to display an image along with the event "title"? (The events would be categorized and there would be a separate image for each category. )
2. On the week/day views, can an image be displayed along with other information?

I've read through the documentation and dozens and dozens of the questions here (and learned a lot from the answers), but didn't see this addressed.  (A background image for the event won't work for this.) If I replace the title text with the img tag, the tag itself is displayed rather than rendering the image.

I'm a rookie at this (jQuery, etc.), so sorry if this is a silly question.  I'm off to read the documentation again.

Comment: checked http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=78 ??

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  (Sorry for not responding sooner!)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another name value pair to the data-in. In this case, I have added ...imageurl:value...

```
[{title:'Language - Session Title',dow:[1,2,4], start:'10:30:00', end: '11:00:00'},
{imageurl:'images/flag/flag_india.png', title: 'Meeting',start:'2017-04-25T10:30:00'}];


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
......
eventRender: function(event, eventElement, view) {
    if (event.imageurl) {eventElement.find(".fc-title").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl +"'> ");}}
    ......
}
```